# Why is TCP server receiving corrupted messages?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to set up TCP/UDP server hosting on the same port.
UDP part is working fine but TCP part doesn't receive messages properly.
I tried testing it with netcat eg. when I send "TCP y u do dis" it outputs something like "D(" and keeps spinning in do while loop.

```
    //Creating TCP listen socket
    tcp_listenfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&tcp_servaddr, sizeof(tcp_servaddr));
    tcp_servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    tcp_servaddr.sin_port=htons(atoi(tcp_port));
    tcp_servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //Binding TCP socket
    setsockopt(tcp_listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));
    bind(tcp_listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&tcp_servaddr,sizeof(tcp_servaddr));
    listen(tcp_listenfd, 10);

    //Creating UDP listen socket
    udp_listenfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bzero(&udp_servaddr, sizeof(udp_servaddr));
    udp_servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    udp_servaddr.sin_port=htons(atoi(udp_port));
    udp_servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //Binding UDP listen socket
    bind(udp_listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&udp_servaddr, sizeof(udp_servaddr));

    //Clear descriptor set
    FD_ZERO(&rset);

    //Max file descriptor
    maxfd = max(tcp_listenfd, udp_listenfd)+1;

    while(1){
        // set listenfd and udpfd in readset
        FD_SET(tcp_listenfd, &rset);
        FD_SET(udp_listenfd, &rset);

        nready = select(maxfd, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(tcp_listenfd, &rset)) {
            printf("TCP ready!\n");
            len=sizeof(cli_addr);
            connfd = accept(tcp_listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &len);
            do {
                numbytes=recv(tcp_listenfd, tcp_buff, sizeof(tcp_buff), 0);
                printf("Received message: %s\n", tcp_buff);
            }while(strcmp(tcp_buff, "HELLO\n")!=0);
            send(tcp_listenfd, payload, strlen(payload)+1, 0);
            close(connfd);
            bzero(&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(udp_listenfd, &rset)){
            printf("UDP ready!\n");
            len=sizeof(cli_addr);
            do{
                recvfrom(udp_listenfd, udp_buff, 1024, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &len);
            }while(strcmp(udp_buff, "HELLO\n")!=0);
            sendto(udp_listenfd, payload, strlen(payload)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, len);
            close(udp_listenfd);
            bzero(&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you printed out the value returned by `recv()`?  Since TCP is a streaming protocol, even on success it can be any value between 1 and `sizeof(tcp_buff)`, and in particular the number of bytes that any given call to `recv()` writes into the buffer is not guaranteed to be the same as the number of bytes passed to any earlier `send()` call in the sending program.  Also note that `printf("%s", [...])` assumes that the string you pass it will be NUL/0 terminated, which might not be the case after `recv()` returns, since `recv()` works at the binary level and doesn't follow C-string semantics.

Comment: Return value from recv() is -1. String is null terminated, I've tested it with other program client.c that sends null terminated string via TCP.

Comment: @user3104311that is not good enough.  Read what Jeremy commented again, carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is here:

```
 connfd = accept(tcp_listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &len);
 do {
    numbytes=recv(tcp_listenfd, tcp_buff, sizeof(tcp_buff), 0);
```

In your `recv()` call you are passing in `tcp_listenfd` when you should be passing in `connfd` instead.  (Also you should be checking the return values of all function calls to make sure that the function succeeded, and taking appropriate action (such as printing an error message via `perror()`) if the function calls failed.  See the man page for each function for details about what return-values constitute success vs failure for that function)